# java Как узнать в каком столбце матрицы сумма элементов(по модулю) максимальная

Tags: java, массивы, матрицы

Сейчас программа уже считает сумму элементов в каждом столбце матрицы.Проблема именно с тем как сравнить теперь эти суммы.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Transpose {
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [][] mas = new int [3][3];

        for(int i =0; i<mas.length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<mas[i].length; j++){
        mas[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*9-1);
        System.out.print(mas[i][j]+" ");
        }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int max = mas[0][0];
        int min = mas[0][0];
        int value = 0;
        int maxsum=0;

        for(int i =0; i<mas[0].length; i++){
        for(int j =0; j<mas.length; j++) {

        if(max < mas[j][i]){
        max=mas[j][i];
        }
        if(min > mas[j][i]){
        min=mas[j][i];

        }
        value+=mas[j][i];
        }

            System.out.println("Сумма элементов столбца  " + (i+1) + ": " + value);



        max = min = value = 0;
        }


        }}
```

Comment: Нет никакой проблемы.

Comment: у меня есть проблема

Comment: Тогда расскажите подробнее, почему для вас проблема сравнить два числа, учитывая, что в коде это уже делается как минимум дважды.

Comment: Ну во-первых, всё-таки три числа, так как у матрицы 3 столбца int [][] mas = new int [3][3]; А вообще, не знаю почему мои попытки не увенчались успехом

Comment: Даже три числа (и вообще любое количество) можно сравнить по два. Сделайте отдельную переменную и сравнивайте сразу после подсчёта суммы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Transpose {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = 3;
        int[][] mas = new int[size][size];

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
                mas[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 - 50);
                System.out.print(mas[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int[] sums = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
                int elem_module = Math.abs(mas[j][i]);
                sums[i] += elem_module;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Сумма элементов столбца " + (i + 1) + " : " + sums[i]);
        }

        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
            if (sums[i] > max) max = sums[i];
        }
        System.out.println("MAX: " + max);

    }}
```